# How to progressively enhance inline block pagination links with respect to the spaces between the links

Tags: css

I'm using [will_paginate](http://rubydoc.info/gems/larsklevan-will_paginate/2.3.12/WillPaginate/ViewHelpers), and it produces pagination links that amount to the following:

```
<a href="?page=2">2</a> <a href="?page=3">3</a>
```

There is whitespace generated between the page links. This makes sense. Just as it says in the documentation, it works well in text-based browsers and spiders (although intuitively, I don't see why the latter would be the case). Wonderful.

I want to center the links as a group. The only way (I know of) to accomplish this is to make them inline elements and to give their parent element `text-align: center;`.

But I'd also like to have better control over the space between the elements.

So to summarize, here are my *nice to haves*:

- whitespace between links
- links collectively centered
- fine-tuned (pixel-level) control for spacing between links

I can think of a few ways to accomplish this:

- refactor the pagination links into an **unordered list**, so that non-graphic browsers will at least render the distinctness between the links independently of the whitespace between them
- set the parent element to have `font-size: 0px;` and then explicitly declare the font size of the individual links

This both appeal to me as less than ideal. The first requires a lot of extraneous markup and it semantically poor in my view. The second seems to be a bit hackish.

Is there any solution that better actually meets my desires without any extra issues? Perhaps something like a CSS directive to ignore whitespace or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using float on the links and float them inside a box that is then center aligned:

http://jsfiddle.net/AnN9n/1/

Comment: Genius! What a wonderful idea. This accomplishes everything I require. My minor semantic revision replaces the extraneous `clear: both;` element with a `overflow: hidden;` in the parent to bound the flow. http://jsfiddle.net/AnN9n/2/

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the correction, we both learnt something new today :)