# Layout difference between floated inline-blocks and non-floated

Tags: html, css-float, compass-sass, css

I'm trying to achieve a simple layout of 4 horizontal inline-blocks within a container.

The HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="myList">
        <li><p>1</p></li>
        <li><p>2</p></li>
        <li><p>3</p></li>
        <li><p>4</p></li>        
    </ul>
</div>​
```

I'd like to evenly lay the li's out horizontally.  I'm using [Compass](http://www.compass-style.org) and applying the following:

```
ul#mylist {
    @include reset-box-model;
    @include inline-block-list-container;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 180px;
    width: 640px;

    > li { 
        @include reset-box-model;
        @include inline-block-list-item(0px);
        width: 130px;
        height: 130px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px 5px;
    }
}
```

See the [resultant HTML/CSS code and output on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BL2Wq/7/).  Despite the dimensions of the li's seeming to fit...

```
(130px + (2 * 5px) + (2 * 10px) = 640px)) * 4 = 640px
```

... the 4th block is pushed down to the next line.

The li's only fit horizontally if I add a *float: left;* to the li's-  see the [resulting HTML/CSS code and output on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HD5Se/4/).

Just wondering if anyone can explain what is going on with this please?  I would have thought that the float: left; would not have been necessary since the dimensions of the inline-block li's fit?  Thank you very much.

Comment: This has been [asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4716247/600101).

Comment: Inline blocks cannot float. The moment you float an element, it is always rendered as a block-level box, not an inline-level block box.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I'll study those questions/answers to try to get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display: inline-block will take into account any surrounding white space. So the line breaks between your li elements are contributing to the width

Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/BL2Wq/8/

Edit: In-depth article on the issue: [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: Great - appreciate your explanation and the link to the article, which I will study.  Thank you.