# hover box on navigation menu

Tags: html, navigation, hover, nav

So i wanted to add a hover box like the one i currently have set on the active link "home" to the other links but when i tried to add it the navigation menu would move place when i hovered so i was hoping for some assistance.

http://trulyamped.com/test/index.html 
http://trulyamped.com/test/styles.css

just view source and let me know what i need to fix.

Thanks everyone.

And as an extra i also was wondering about adding a slight delay/fade when you hover off of a menu-item.   ex: like i hover over "contact" and it turns blue but when i hover off it takes like half a second or something to fade away.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes:

LN9: remove

LN12: padding: 0px 24px;

LN25-28: updated hover

LN36-36: removed

LN77-78: removed

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;   
}
header {
    height: 95px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 24px;
}
a:link    {
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration: none;

    }
a:visited  {
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
a:hover    {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FF6850;
    padding-top: 38px;
    padding-bottom: 34px;
    color: white;
}
a:active   {
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration: none;

    }
a.active{
    background-color: #FF6850;
    padding-top: 38px;
    padding-bottom: 34px;
    color: white;
}

#longbar {
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: auto;
    clear: both;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url(images/header/topbar.jpg);
}
#longbarmini {
    min-width: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #FF6850;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#wrapper header h1 {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    color: #0078D4;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
}
#wrapper header h1 span {
    color: #316ca7;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
#wrapper header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;   
    font-size: 18px;
}
#wrapper header ul li {
    display: inline;
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration: none;

}

section {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #AE4639;
}
#content {
    height: 100px;
    width: 800px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #0FF;
}
footer  {
    min-width: 1000px;
    clear: both;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: thanks that works, but what if i wanted to increase the width of the color? like the left and the right?

Comment: By the way, you asked about delay on hover. You can do this animation using javascript. There is an example with jquery: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/UIElements/LargeDropDown

LN189-215

Comment: sweet thanks a bunch, i see the error was on my padding-right and the word spacing - i always make do something like that and then i can't find that one error. thanks Warlock.  and ill look at the jquery link you sent me, i was searching for one before but just came across a bunch of other things. thanks again

Comment: not a huge thing, but ....by any chance you know how to decrease the white space inbetween the hover and the active?

Comment: This is a good question, that was asked in another thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716151/css-removing-horizontal-space-in-list-menu-using-display-inline-property

Comment: The simplest solution is to add "float: left;" inside #wrapper header ul li{}

Comment: thanks again that worked and i also found another way by doing a margin: -1px; to the a tag. thanks